# Postgresql Select data between selected dates and status

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

In my Java Web application I use Postgresql and some data tables are filled automatically in server. In the database I have a STATUS table like below:

[image]

I want to select the data related to a vehicle between selected dates and where the vehicle stayed connected. Simply I want to select the data which are green in the above table which means I exactly want the data when firstly connected=true and the data when connected=false after the last connected=true. I tried to write a sql statement but I couldn't get the desired data.

What I did was:

```
select *from status where vehicleId='redcar' and 
date >= '2014-02-28 00:00:00' and date <= '2014-02-28 23:59:59' and ...
```

How could I get the requested data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT statusId, vehicleId, connected, date,
           (connected <> LAG(connected) OVER (PARTITION BY vehicleId 
                                              ORDER BY date)
           ) AS status_changed
    FROM status 
    WHERE vehicleId = 'redcar' 
      AND date >= DATE '2014-02-28' 
      AND date <  DATE '2014-02-28' + interval '1 day'
  ) 
SELECT statusId, vehicleId, connected, date
FROM cte
WHERE status_changed 
   OR connected AND status_changed IS NULL 
ORDER BY date ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0072d/24)**

Comment: your answer worked greatly. It gives the desired data with the desired order. However, I want to retrieve all the fields in the STATUS table. Also, does this answer work with Hibernate? thank you.

Comment: If the table has more columns than the 4 shown, then simply replace the `SELECT statusId, vehicleId, connected, date` (twice)  with the columns you want. No idea about Hibernate, sorry.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I will post another question related to Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html).

Something like this:

```
with status_changes as(
        select
             id,
             vehicleid,
             connected,
             connected != lag(connected)
                 over (partition by vehicleid
                       order by date asc) as has_changed
         from STATUS
)
select
    id,
    vehicleid, 
    connected,
    date
from status_changes
where has_changed = true
      and vehicle = 'redcar'
      and date between '2014-02-28 00:00:00' and '2014-02-28 23:59:59';
```

- **lag(status)**  will return the status that preceded it (within our partition).
- **partition by vehicleid** (with an order by date) ensures that our *lag()* returns rows of the same vehicleid.

See the list of [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html) for more on *lag()* and related functions.

Comment: +1 Much simpler than mine. I may have over thought it somewhat!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [Gaps and Islands](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/the-sql-of-gaps-and-islands-in-sequences/) logic:

```
SELECT  VehicleID, Connected, MIN(Date) AS Date
FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID ORDER BY Date) - 
                        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID, Connected ORDER BY Date) AS GroupingSet,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN Connected THEN Date END) OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID) AS FirstConnected
            FROM    status
            WHERE   VehicleID = 'redcar'
            AND     date >= '2014-02-28 00:00:00' 
            AND     date < '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
        ) s
WHERE   Date > FirstConnected
GROUP BY VehicleID, Connected, GroupingSet
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0072d/3)**

If you also need to retrieve the `StatusID` you will need to add a further ranking function and only select only the first row:

```
SELECT  StatusID,
        VehicleID, 
        Connected, 
        Date
FROM    (   SELECT  StatusID,
                    VehicleID, 
                    Connected, 
                    Date,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID, Connected, GroupingSet ORDER BY Date) AS RowNumber
            FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                                DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID ORDER BY Date) - 
                                    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID, Connected ORDER BY Date) AS GroupingSet,
                                MIN(CASE WHEN Connected THEN Date END) OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID) AS FirstConnected
                        FROM    status
                        WHERE   VehicleID = 'redcar'
                        AND     date >= '2014-02-28 00:00:00' 
                        AND     date < '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
                    ) s
            WHERE   Date > FirstConnected
        ) s
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0072d/5)**

Or use `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT ON (VehicleID, Connected, GroupingSet) 
        StatusID, 
        VehicleID, 
        Connected, 
        Date
FROM    (   SELECT  *,
                    DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID ORDER BY Date) - 
                        DENSE_RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID, Connected ORDER BY Date) AS GroupingSet,
                    MIN(CASE WHEN Connected THEN Date END) OVER(PARTITION BY VehicleID) AS FirstConnected
            FROM    status
            WHERE   VehicleID = 'redcar'
            AND     date >= '2014-02-28 00:00:00' 
            AND     date < '2014-03-01 00:00:00'
        ) s
WHERE   Date > FirstConnected
ORDER BY VehicleID, Connected, GroupingSet
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0072d/6)**

Comment: @zamansafari you can change the `ORDER BY` at the end to meet your needs.

Comment: Your answer works greatly but the order of data is mixed. Actually my STATUS table has many more feilds. I want to retrieve the selected rows containing all the columns and the retrieved data should be ordered by vehicleId and date in ASC order. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @GarethD, your last answer works fine and very fast. The order of data is mixed. I changed the ORDER BY order; however, I couldn't get the desired order of data. It should be ordered by vehicle id and date in ASC order. Also I want to retrieve all the fields of table.

Comment: You would need to wrap this in a subquery, `DISTINCT ON` requires that the distinct fields appear first in the order by clause